# Wordpress product Page not Found

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, url, http-status-code-404

столкнулся с проблемой со ссылками на товары - все работало, после установки плагина Product Size Charts Plugin for WooCommerce а также добавления атрибута размера получаю 404 на любом продукте. Плагин уже удалил, также как и атрибут, тем не менее проблема осталась. Прикрепляю скриншот настроек постоянных ссылок и ниже код htaccess. Все возможные способы изложенные в интернете уже пробовал, подскажите кто знает

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]